Why is this considered "BAD" layout for an inductor
I want to know if this is a "BAD" way to route an inductor that is applied in a SMPS. From my understanding (which could be wrong) the fields will look like this:

As per the Top and Bottom layers below there is ground around the entire two SW pads. Hence is it bad to have the SW1 and SW2 pours on the top and bottom layer and connected using vias?
The fields will be confined because the ground pours are on the sides and the middle under the inductor.
Top layer

Bottom layer

EDIT 1:
Datasheet for inductor

@All - Although well-intentioned, the long comment chain has exceeded what is reasonable for comments. Therefore comments so far have been moved to chat & should be continued there (see link in the comment below). || As this bulk moving of comments to chat can only be done once per question, any further comments posted here may be deleted without notice. Keep it in chat now, please! || Any improvement / clarification to the question decided during the chat, should be made via an [edit], not as a comment. When someone has enough information to post an answer, please answer it as usual. TY

Comments have been moved to this chatroom and discussion should be continued there. Please do not continue the discussion in comments here.
